# Spring Boot and Hibernate 5

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-5.x

I am very new to Spring Boot. I am trying to add Hibernate 5 to my Spring Boot project and make it to work.
My config class:

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
...
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(value = { "boot.entities" })
@PropertySources(value = { @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:db-        connection.properties", "hibernate.properties" }) })
public class Config {

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.connection.url"));
    ...
    return ds;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    ...
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager geTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}   
}
```

my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-    plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
...
dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
// runtime('com.h2database:h2')

// ### hibernate 5
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.4.Final'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-dbcp2', version: '2.1.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-pool2', version: '2.4.2'
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.21'
compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
compile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.21.0-GA'

testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

and the error trying to start:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/MetadataBuilder
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
at boot.config.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [bin/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/MetadataBuilder
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.MetadataBuilder
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
... 27 common frames omitted
```

I thank you in advance for the help! And sorry for my english!

Comment: Is there a reason why you insist on using Hibernate 5.2 rather than 5.0 (the one Boot provides by default). You most probably have mixed versions of hibernate on the classpath. Also 100% of your configuration is auto-configured by Boot. You can actually remove _everything_ and use standard configuration keys for the datasource and you'll get the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, Stephane! I am thinking in "Spring" and not according Spring Boot. I was trying to init a datasource for a Postgresql db without considering the application.properties file which to leverage on during configuration process.

Comment: Well, you are using Spring Boot aren't you? There's nothing else to consider in my view. If you start a Spring Boot app you'll get that out of the box. Is there a reason why you're not considering this?

Comment: I fear to loose control on my app.
But after all you are perfectly right!

Comment: Well, your app doesn't start at all right now so that's no better. And if things improve/change, you'll have to take care of that yourself. Again, that's something Spring Boot does for you, there's no reason to fight it IMO. Give it a try and feel free to create another thread if that doesn't work.